# Microsoft Teams and Skype For Business issue - multiple conversation with the same user

Tags: microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

I have a very strange issue with Teams and Skype for Business.

I have a customer (outside of my company), who was using Skype For Business. He was using an SFB self-hosted server.
I was also using Skype For Business with my Office 365 tenant at this time because Teams was not yet created. And we have set the federation between my customer's domain and mine, so we were able to chat on Skype For Business.

A few years ago, I migrated to Teams. I was able to see my customer (who was still in Skype For Business) in my Teams and I was able to chat with him. I was not able to share my desktop with him except in Teams meeting, but I know that this is a limitation due to the cohabitation between Teams and SFB.

Now my customer moved to Teams. When we chat in Teams, I have two separate discussions:

- One discussion where I can talk with him, marked with a small Skype logo -> my customer can only read this conversation, he can't respond;
- One discussion where I receive the response from my customer and where I can't respond...

This means that I have two separate discussions in Teams for each member of the customer crew... And I don't know how to merge or remove one.
The customer has the exact same situation on its side.

Comment: What coexistence mode is set for your account and what is set for your customer?

Comment: For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).
For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum)